# remove menuitems in android menu by title name

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, menuitem

Is there a way for me to remove menuitems pragmatically in the navigation drawer if I am using a menu xml?

```
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_inbox" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_inbox"
        android:title="Inbox" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_news" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_news"
        android:title="News" />        
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_my_profile" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_arrow_closed"
        android:title="My Profile" />
```

Let's say I want searched for all the menuitems that have the word "pro", which means that other menuitems should not be shown except for "My Profile" item.

I'm thinking it's related to

```
setEnabled(false)
```

syntax but I'm clueless how.

This is my current syntax for the searchbar:

```
  mSearchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {



        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

I am still clueless on how I'll tackle it.

Is it possible that I could disable the other menuitems so only the searched item will be shown?

Comment: Which navigation drawer are you using? Can't you use `setVisibility(false)` on the menu item you want to hide?

Answer (score 0):

```
setVisibility(false);
```

in activity :

```
setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or

```
setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the `setVisibility` of respective `View` for it.You can check details from [Android Developers Guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int))

Just set different parameters of `setVisibility`function according to your need. For Example ...

```
setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

OR

```
setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

You can check official documentation of [GONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) and [INVISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) for the difference.

Then if you want to show those menu items again , you can use

```
setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Check detail of using [VISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE)